# OpenVPN overrides gateways

Tags: openvpn

I have problem with OpenVPN on Linux, because it overrides my gateways, so all network traffic goes through VPN tunnel. I want to push through tunnel only traffic from specific subnet. My routes without OpenVPN running:

```
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

After enabling VPN:

```
default         172.22.73.193   128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
static-78-8-9-5 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
172.22.73.192   *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

I tried to delete first route with command `sudo route del default gw 172.22.73.193`, but it always fails with `SIOCDELRT: No such process`.

Can I achieve that by changing OpenVPN

Comment: Do post your OVPN client config file

Comment: Shouldn't that be `route del -net default gw 172.22.73.193`?

Answer (score 1):

The server you are connecting to is *probably* an Online VPN Service Provider, which uses `push "redirect-gateway"` to send ALL your client data over the VPN.  To stop this you can add `route-nopull` to your client config file.